# How to use Sweet Alerts in my website..?

Tags: javascript, html

I use "Sweetalerts" in my page.
I've a static link which should redirect to "google.com". When i click on the link it shall show an alert message stating

> if you click OK you will be redirected to google.com

As soon as one hits "OK" the redirection takes place.

The problem is that I'm able to see the alert message while clicking on the link, but the button doesn't work. It just closes the alert message instead of redirecting to the appropriated link.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the callback function of swal? Something like

```
swal({   
   title: "Are you sure?",   
   text: "If you click OK you will be redirected to google.com",   
   type: "warning",   
   showCancelButton: true,   
   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
   confirmButtonText: "OK",   
   closeOnConfirm: true}, 
   function(){ 
        window.location.href = "www.google.com"; 
   });
```

If you post Code snippet, it will help other users to understand the issue.

Comment: This cannot be an answer to the question, it must be in the comments section

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Working Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/rovapi  . If it solves your question, please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  swal({ 
  title: "Alert",
   text: "Redirecting to google",
    type: "success" 
  },
  function(){
    window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Swal Alert has an option for callback functions that run after an action.

```
swal({   title: "Are you sure?" },
     function(){  window.location.href = "www.google.com";  });
```